# Symfony Random url showing 404

Tags: php, symfony

I am working through the random number generator in the cookbook how ever when I try to access `app_dev.php/random` I am getting 404 and the same for `app_dev.php`.

My server is running cPanel and I installed Symfony via `scriptalicious`

When I load `domain.co.nz/symfony` I get

**Page Message:**

Symfony is installed successfully.

Symfony is a Framework, so doesn't have an index page.

How could I resolve my above issues?

**Routing:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$ranNum = $loader->import('@DemoRandomNumberBundle/Resources/config/routing.php');
$ranNum->addPrefix('/');

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('random', new Route('/random{limit}', array('_controller' => 'DemoBundle:Random:index')));

return $collection;
```

Comment: Did you set the routing correctly? Can you show the specific part of code?

Comment: what is the output of `app:console Router:debug` from the terminal? Did you cleared the symfony2 cache? I don't see a mistake on the first sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is at the url/path `/random{limit}` while you are requesting `/random` so it isn't finding anything.

The regex for routing parameters is `[^/]+` meaning that it needs one or more characters, which you are not providing.

To get to your page you would need you use that parameter in your url like `/random123` with `123` being `limit`.